# Check the quality of wifi connectivity?

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I ran into the case that when I had 4G off and connected to certain wifi access point but without capability to send out or receive data, the flag used to check the connectivity of network was set to be true like below.

```
NetworkInfo ni = context.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean flag = ni.isConnected();
```

In this case, I should obviously drop the wifi and switch on my 4G or in other words turn to use my 4g instead of wifi network.
But How could I check the quality of wifi connectivity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can check the speed in the mobile network using this code,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class Connectivity {
    /*
     * HACKISH: These constants aren't yet available in my API level (7), but I need to handle these cases if they come up, on newer versions
     */
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD=14; // Level 11
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B=12; // Level 9
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP=15; // Level 13
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN=11; // Level 8
    public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_LTE=13; // Level 11

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }
    /**
     * Check if there is fast connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }

    /**
     * Check if the connection is fast
     * @param type
     * @param subType
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            System.out.println("CONNECTED VIA WIFI");
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return false; // ~ 100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
            // NOT AVAILABLE YET IN API LEVEL 7
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
                return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
                return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return false; // ~25 kbps 
            case Connectivity.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                return false; 
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: That doesn't check the quality of the wi-fi connection, it just says that if wi-fi, it's fast... doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone running into this question, here's an answer from Sep 8, 2015

https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class

> **Network Connection Class**
>
> Network Connection Class is an Android library that allows you to
>   figure out the quality of the current user's internet connection. The
>   connection gets classified into several "Connection Classes" that make
>   it easy to develop against. The library does this by listening to the
>   existing internet traffic done by your app and notifying you when the
>   user's connection quality changes. Developers can then use this
>   Connection Class information and adjust the application's behaviour
>   (request lower quality images or video, throttle type-ahead, etc).
>
> Network Connection Class currently only measures the user's downstream
>   bandwidth. Latency is also an important factor, but in our tests,
>   we've found that bandwidth is a good proxy for both.
>
> The Network Connection Class library takes care of spikes using a
>   moving average of the incoming samples, and also applies some
>   hysteresis (both with a minimum number of samples and amount the
>   average has to cross a boundary before triggering a bucket change)