# How to Get/Check The Internet Connection Strength in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to get/check internet connection strength in android studio?We can check whether internet is there or not ? But because of less internet strength developed android apps may crash

Thanks in advance

Comment: While it can be useful to know if you have a connection (and, perhaps, even how strong it is), it's more important to make sure you apps _don't_ crash if the connection is lost. Losing a connection can happen at any time: in the middle of being used or a fraction of a second after checking that it was "OK". All communications need to anticipate the connection dying and take appropriate action (e.g. automatically retry; store the request for later; alert the user). At at a minimum, "appropriate action" is don't crash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

It's about connectivity status and type, from connectivity type you can assume a quality of service, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088823

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    public String ConnectionQuality() {
    NetworkInfo info = getInfo(context);
    if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
      return "UNKNOWN";
    }

    if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int numberOfLevels = 5;
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
        if(level == 2 )
                return "POOR";
            else if(level == 3 )
                return "MODERATE";
            else if(level == 4 )
                return "GOOD";
            else if(level == 5 )
                return "EXCELLENT";
            else
            return "UNKNOWN";
        }else if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            int networkClass = getNetworkClass(getNetworkType(context));
            if(networkClass == 1)
                return "POOR";
            else if(networkClass == 2 )
                return "GOOD";
            else if(networkClass == 3 )
                return "EXCELLENT";
            else
                return "UNKNOWN";
        }else
            return "UNKNOWN";  
}



public NetworkInfo getInfo(Context context) {
    return ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
}



public int getNetworkClass(int networkType) {
    try {
      return getNetworkClassReflect(networkType);
    }catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    switch (networkType) {
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
      case 16: // TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
        return 1;
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
      case 17: // TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA:
        return 2;
      case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
      case 18: // TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN:
        return 3;
      default:
        return 0;
    }
}

private int getNetworkClassReflect(int networkType) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {  
    Method getNetworkClass = TelephonyManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getNetworkClass", int.class);
    if (!getNetworkClass.isAccessible()) {
      getNetworkClass.setAccessible(true);
    }
    return (Integer) getNetworkClass.invoke(null, networkType); 
}

public static int getNetworkType(Context context) {
    return ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getNetworkType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int numberOfLevels = 5;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);

    switch (level)
    {
        case 0:
            Log.d("LEVEL","None");
            break;

        case 1:
            Log.d("LEVEL","None");
            break;

        case 2:
            Log.d("LEVEL","Poor");
            break;

        case 3:
            Log.d("LEVEL","Moderate");
            break;

        case 4:
            Log.d("LEVEL","Good");
            break;

        case 5:
            Log.d("LEVEL","Excellent");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is working for only Wifi Strength not for Mobile Internet.Can You Please Tell me How Get/Check for Mobile Internet Too?