# How streaming apps change video quality based on changes in network speed?

Tags: android, performance, mvvm, architecture

How streaming apps like Youtube, Hotstar or any other video player app, programmatically detects if network is getting slow over run-time and based on that they change video quality based on changes in network speed?

Answer (score 2):

Many streaming services nowadays use HTTP-based streaming protocols. But there are exceptions; especially with low-latency streaming; e.g. WebRTC or Websocket-based solutions.

Assuming that you're using a HTTP-based protocol like HLS or MPEG-DASH, the "stream" is a long chain of video segments that are downloaded one after another. A video segment is a file in "TS" or "MP4" format (in some MP4 cases, video and audio are splitted into separate files); typically a segment has 2 or 6 or 10 seconds of audio and/or video.

Based on the playlist or manifest (or sometimes simply from decoding the segment), the player knows how many seconds of a single segment contains. It also knows how long it took to download that segment. You can measure the available bandwidth by diving the (average) size of a video segment file by the (average) time it took to download.

At the moment that it takes more time to download a segment than to play it, you know that the player will stall as soon as the buffer is empty; stalling is generally referred to as "buffering". Adaptive Bitrate (aka. ABR) is a technique that tries to prevent buffering; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming (or Google for the expression) - when the player notices that the available bandwidth is lower than the bit rate of the video stream, it can switch to another version of the same stream that has a lower bit rate (typically achieved by higher compression and/or lower resolution - which results in less quality, but that's better than buffering)

PS #1: WebRTC and Websocket-based streaming solutions cannot use this measuring trick and must implement other solutions

PS #2: New/upcoming variants of HLS (eg. LL-HLS and LHLS) and MPEG-DASH use other HTTP technologies (like chunked-transfer or HTTP PUSH) to achieve lower latency - these typically do not work well with the mentioned measuring technique and use different techniques which I consider outside scope here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a streaming server in order to do that. Wowza server is one of them (not free). The client and server will exchange information about the connexion and distribute chuncks of the video, depending on the network speed.

Comment: My question is more related with how on client end on Android these apps detects the change in speed of network in run-time.

Comment: OK then you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088823, because I don't think I can help you to do better than what a library does. I mean it's complicated to have the real connection quality, you need to test it (for example calculate on the client the duration of the download for a chuck of video) the most simple is to use this answer in the to have an approximation

Comment: @liltof that code only returns true or false based on a bandwidth "type" and doesn't (1) tell how you found the current bandwidth type or (2) relate to the bitrate of the video.